# Detect face with HAAR Classifier

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, haar-classifier

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{

    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat Ycbcr;
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(images[i], faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

    for (int l = 0; l < faces.size(); l++)
    {
        Point center(faces[l].x + faces[l].width*0.5, faces[l].y + faces[l].height*0.5);

        Mat temp = x.clone();
        Ycbcr = temp(faces[l]); //do something}}
```

This code gives me an error from line `face_cascade.detectMultiScale(images[i], faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));` in the second iterate. What can be the cause

Comment: tell us the error message please...

Comment: what is "images"? Maybe size is only 1?